Error while loading model using Tensorflow and Keras in VS Code
I trained a model in Jupyter notebook and then saved it using model.save(modelName.h5) and then I tried to load that model in my VS Code for creating the frontend and backend but on loading it in VS Code, I am getting this error :
ValueError : Unknown layer : Please ensure you are using a kerbs.utils.custom_object_scope and that this object is included in the scope.
If someone knows how to fix it please help.
Thanks in advance.
I trained a model in Jupyter notebook and then saved it using model.save(modelName.h5) and then I tried to load that model in my VS Code for creating the frontend and backend but on loading it in VS Code, I am getting error.

See here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/serialization_and_saving#custom_objects

I tried it but it is not working. Any other solution? @mhenning

Please show your code then, how the model looks and how you save it.
